# Is there a web app where can I search for books by tag?

Tags: web-apps, search

Is there a web application where can I search for books by tag? Not by its genre but rather by reader-subjective applied tag, for example I'd like to see all books which have something to do with snow, skiing, winter, Arctic and things like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I realise you asked this almost a year ago, but in the event you still you haven't found something, I thought I'd answer your question.*

The closest thing I know of to what you're looking for is **[Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com)**. In addition to allowing users to categorise books by the usual genres, Goodreads also allows them to be sorted into what it calls "Shelves". Shelves are sub-genres that function as more powerful extensions of the usual genres; they're created by users to categorise the books that they save, and they can describe anything from mood to era to aesthetic, making them *essentially tags by another name*.

You can find all the Shelves that are available here:

**https://www.goodreads.com/genres/list**

And the following screenshots narrow down books by the <s>tags</s> Shelves you were looking for.

## Snow:

[image]

## Arctic:

[image]

## Skiing:

[image]

The only disadvantage of using Goodreads is that Shelves seem to be a relatively underutilised feature, especially in proportion to the rest of the site's functionality. This leaves open the possibility that there exists a web app out there which is both designed with tagging in mind and has a user base that utilises that functionality more, making it a better fit for you than Goodreads is - but again, I don't personally know of one.

In addition, it's worth bearing in mind that Goodreads is c*urrently the  largest, longest established, and most popular book-logging/cataloguing web app out there* - being currently owned by Amazon - so there's a good chance that the sheer size of its user base makes its current tagging functionality a lot more useful to you than if you were to find a more focused but relatively obscure alternative.